# Why MYSQLi does not update the DB record, but it does provide a successful message

Tags: php, mysql

Why MYSQLi does not update the DB record, but it does provide a successful message. Of course, with the following message: 0 records UPDATED successfully And no changes are made to the database.

my index php file code:

```
<?php

include 'connect.php';

$work = $_GET["work"];


if($work == "select"){

$query = "SELECT * FROM login ORDER BY City DESC";
$result = $connect->prepare($query);
$result ->execute();

$out = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$record = array();
$record["InsID"] = $row["InsID"];

$record["Password"] = $row["Password"];

$record["Name"] = $row["Name"];

$record["City"] = $row["City"];

array_push($out,$record);

}

echo json_encode($out);

} elseif($work  == "update"){

$name2 = $_REQUEST["Ali"];

$code2 = $_REQUEST["4779"];

$city2 = $_REQUEST["teh"];

$pass2 = $_REQUEST["123"];

$query2 = "UPDATE login SET Password='$pass2',Name='$name2',City='$city2' WHERE InsID = '$code2'";

$result2 = $connect->prepare($query2);

$result2 ->execute();


}

?>
```

I really do not know where my coding is wrong. Please help.

Comment: How did you know that something was updated? There is no code checking this. Additionally, your code is widely open to SQL injections and does not check whether errors occured on inserting the data

Comment: @NicoHaase  i am going to the database table after running this code and seeing nothing has changed. can you help me?

Comment: Yes, what about checking for errors? ;)

Comment: @NicoHaase the result is field. what should i do?

Comment: I don't know which kind of database class you use, but there is something like `mysqli_error` available. If something went wrong, it returns the error message of the MySQL server, and most likely, this tells you where the operation went wrong.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this code 
May be useful

```
$query2 = "UPDATE login SET Password='$pass2',Name='$name2',City='$city2' WHERE InsID = '$code2';

if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect)==1){

echo "updated successfully";
}
else{
echo "failed";
}
```

Comment: The result is the field. What should I do?

Comment: the result is field. what should i do?

Comment: @pooja can you explain how syntactically wrong code can be useful? Can you highlight the parts that are important?

Comment: @NicoHaase The update command does not work in my coding and does not change the database information. please help me

Comment: @JavadMahmoodi have you read my last comment on your question? Read out the errors provided by `mysqli_error` (or whatever your database library provides)

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you are updating InsID and also using  `'where InsID like'`

Also there is additional **;** in query

You may try

```
$query2 = "UPDATE login SET Password='$pass2',Name='$name2',City='$city2' WHERE InsID like '$code2'";
```

Important = sanitize input data first**

Answer (score 0):

if I understand what you're trying to accomplish then :

1. you don't have to set InsID again
2. you need to use = and not LIKE in the WHERE condition

i.e. this is the row you need :

```
 $query2 = "UPDATE login SET Password='$pass2',Name='$name2',City='$city2' WHERE InsID = '$code2';";
```

also see Nico Haase's comment, it's super correct ! you **must** improve the code security, see : http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php